# How does one watch another session on an AS/400?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I was working with a system admin yesterday and there was a vendor in an iSeries working, and he was able to observe the green screen as the vendor worked.

It was like VNC for iSeries; how does one do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like `Start Copy Screen (STRCPYSCN)` command...

[some IBM Documentation.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/ddp/rbal1sci.htm)

> The Start Copy Screen (STRCPYSCN) command allows you to be at your
>   workstation and see the same displays that are seen by someone at
>   another workstation.
>
> You must be signed on to the same IBM® i platform as the user. If that
>   user is on a remote system, you can use display station pass-through
>   to sign on that system, and then enter the STRCPYSCN command to see
>   the other displays. Screen images can be copied to a database file at
>   the same time they are copied to another workstation or when another
>   workstation cannot be used. This allows you to process this data later
>   and prepares an audit trail for the operations that occur during a
>   problem.

Comment: How do I find my display?

Comment: Use `*REQUESTER` for the session you are running the command in

Comment: Is that in the `.ws` file?

Answer (score 1):

[STRCPYSCN](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/cl/strcpyscn.htm)

> The Start Copy Screen (STRCPYSCN) command allows you to copy the screens of another display station on your display station to observe what is happening and diagnose problems.