# What is a "session" on an iSeries / AS400?

Tags: session, ibm-midrange

I was asking another question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/981052/how-does-one-watch-another-session-on-an-as-400) and they stated that I needed `*REQUESTOR` for the session I was running the command in.  What is this session, and how do I find out what it is?  I know about sessions in regards to webservers and such, but the AS400 is a different animal, and I'm not going to assume they're talking about a hashmap that stores variables related to your particular connection to the system.

Comment: @djdomi: I don't want to be rude but even after reading your comment thrice, it is hard if not impossible to get what you mean. Could you please edit and reword to proper english?

Comment: sry, a session is usually just a created user Profile which is"linkes" to a sessioname and hostname, it is also licencing relevant to know how many sessions you need

Comment: @djdomi how do you find it’s identifier?  Is it the login name?

Comment: i only have some spare knowledge since i only installed the Client  part, usually you can find the session name in the client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the linked question, and it appears that you need just a little basic assistance.

When a user opens his 5250 terminal emulator (like iACS 5250 Emulator), and then signs on to IBM i, that is often called opening a session on IBM i. That session is also called an interactive job. The emulator is called a display device by the operating system.

When you type a command on the command line of your terminal display, you can prompt that command by pressing F4. Prompting is what we call asking for context sensitive information based on the location of the cursor. For a command, prompting will display parameters. Try it:

1. Log in to IBM i
2. Type STRCPYSCN on the command line
3. Press F4

You will see a page of parameters. The first two parameters can have a value of *REQUESTER. To see what the parameter values mean, you can put the cursor on the field, and press F1. Generally *REQUESTER, when you see it, will mean your display device, that is, the emulator you are logged in from, or your session. All three of those mean approximately the same thing.